# Using the LDAvis package in R to create a gist file of the result

Tags: json, r, curl, lda

I'm using LDAvis  for topic modeling and trying to use the as.gist option to create a gist. When serVis executes there is a timeout in curl::curl_fetch_memory after about 10 seconds. If I immediately execute serVis again I get a different error 'Problems parsing JSON' and from then on whenever serVis is run that same error recurs.

If I start all over with a fresh workspace the same behavior occurs. The first time serVis is run, curl::curl_fetch_memory times out after about 10 seconds. Subsequent executions return 'Problems parsing JSON'.

If I don't use the as.gist option it works fine, but of course doesn't create a gist.

Very rarely, it works and a gist is created. If I change parameters to reduce the size of the JSON object it usually works, which makes me think it may be related to size.

I have explored the various RCurlOptions timeout settings. Currently, they are set as

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", 
                                             package = "RCurl"),
                        connecttimeout = 300, timeout = 3000,
                        followlocation = TRUE, dns.cache.timeout = 300))
```

Below is a console listing with debug set on curl::curl_fetch_memory.

```
> json <- createJSON(phi            = cases$phi, 
+                    theta          = cases$theta, 
+                    doc.len .... [TRUNCATED] 

> serVis(json, open.browser = TRUE, as.gist = TRUE, description = 'APM Community')
debugging in: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
debug: {
    output <- .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle)
    res <- handle_response_data(handle)
    res$content <- output
    res
    }
Browse[2]> output <- .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle)
Error: Timeout was reached
Browse[2]> output <- .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle)
Browse[2]> rawToChar(output)
[1] "{\"message\":\"Problems parsing     JSON\",\"documentation_url\":\"https://developer.github.com/v3\"}"
Browse[2]> 
.
. 
exiting from: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
Error: Problems parsing JSON
```

Any hints on how to debug this problem?

Comment: This may have been caused by special characters in the json file. I used iconv to convert the input to ascii and since that time I've not had the problem.